# How to allow only certain query string parameters in IIS?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, query-string, url-rewrite-module, requestfiltering

In IIS URL Rewrite, I need to Abort all requests, Excepted those which :

- do not have any querystring parameter
- or
- do have one or more querystring parameters within a limited set of querystring parameters.

Every request with one or more querystring parameters outside of the limited set will get an AbortRequest.

So for example :

- https://mysite123/page.html Will be **accepted**
- https://mysite123/page.html?allowed3=ccc Will be **accepted**
- https://mysite123/page.html?allowed1=aaa&allowed2=bbb Will be **accepted**
- https://mysite123/page.html?allowed1=aaa&disallowed4=nope Will be ***rejected***

I've been playing and fiddling for days, but did not come to a working solution.

---

Here is what I've achieved so far : Parameters **allowed1, ... allowed4** are allowed, but any others are not.

So far, this rule is too permissive, because if I specify the "allowed1" parameter with the "z" parameter, the request is accepted... but I want it to be blocked due to the presence of "z".

The tricky part is that I do now know in advance the order of my allowed parameter, nor their number. A valid request could contain the "allowed1" parameter, or the "allowed1" + "allowed3" parameters, or only "allowed4". But the "z" parameter should be rejected, even if one of the whitelisted ones is present.

```
<rule name="Accept Requests Without parameters, or with Only whitelisted ones" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="((^.{0}$)|(((^|\?|&amp;)(allowed1|allowed2|allowed3|allowed4)=)))" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="AbortRequest"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: You can only achieve that using IIS URL Rewrite module, where you set a condition on query string and check what parameters are there.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. Can you explain to me what is the specific difference between the third url and the fourth url? Both allowed2 and disallowed4 are different from allowed1.

Comment: Hi, @samwu Any URL containing only allowed parameters can be allowed. Requests containing other parameters (like in the 4th example) should be rejected, even if one allowed parameter exists. I've edited my question to reflect what I've achieved so far.

Comment: @LexLi, Yes I agree with you, and I have edited my question. I do not see how to achieve that like you described it... would you have a clue for me?

Comment: I still can’t understand what you mean, which parameters correspond to the four letters abcd?

Comment: a,b,c,d are just some sample allowed parameters. I've edited my question again to match.